# how to share text on facebook using dialog in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I need to share text on facebook. I'm send text programmatically through intent. Code is working and dialog is opened but text is not appearing on share post.

Code :

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    waIntent.setType("text/plain");

                    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    waIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");

                    String msg = "Corporate1 Facebook Post";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Facebook not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question but you might have more control if you use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: plz share your  dialog code?

Comment: can´t you just enter the text in the dialog that pops up?

Comment: Your app is not allowed to prefill the text anyway, it has to be input by the user.

Comment: facebook not allow to post text either using SDK or Intent. its only allow single URL to be post to facebook using Intent. if you want to post some media, you need to use SDK. For text, absolutely can't.